# Is there tool to convert cobol file into csv or json

Tags: cobol, file-format

I have a COBOL file and COBOL copybook. I'm not sure if these files are corrupted or not and I need to convert this data into CSV or JSON.

This is sample of the copybook, I'm not sure if this valid copybook or not.

```
000040* LTOT-TABRU        :INTEREST CODES TABLE  CULCOLATED*                   
000050*  ORGANIZATION     :INDEXED                         *                   
000060*  RECORD KEY       :CLE-TRUT                        *                   
000070******************************************************                   
000090*  CLE-TRUT         :INTEREST CODE                   *                   
000100*  LIB-TRUT         :NAME                            *                   
000120*  MONT-TRUT        :RATE CODE                       *                   
000150******************************************************                   
000160 FD  TOT-TABRU                                                           
000170     LABEL RECORDS ARE  STANDARD                                         
000180     BLOCK CONTAINS 5  RECORDS                                           
000190     RECORD CONTAINS 95 CHARACTERS.                                      
000200 01  ENRE-TRUT.                                                          
000220     02 CLE-TRUT     PIC XXX.                                            
000230     02 LIB-TRUT     PIC X(20).                                          
           02 RATE-ITEM OCCURS 12 TIMES.                                       
000240        03 MONT-TRUT PIC X(6).                                           
              03 MONT-TRUT9 REDEFINES MONT-TRUT PIC 99V9999.
```

Is there a tool to convert this copybook and data file into readable format?

Comment: [Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow  as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Record-Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/), it should be able to display the file (note there is a **Cobol** tab on the *File Open* screen).

The **RecordEditor** can generate scripts for

- [Cobol To Csv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/)
- [Cobol to JSON](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltojson/)
- [Cobol to Xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltoxml/)